# Sort and export-CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file containing rows of the following extract:

> "EmployeeID","FirstName","LastName","Location","Department","TelephoneNo","Email"
>   "000001    ","abc           ","def                       ","Loc1","    ","              ","name1@company.com                                  "
>   "000023    ","ghi           ","jkl                       ","Loc2","  ","              ","name2@company.com                                  "
>   "000089    ","mno           ","pqr                         ","Loc2","               ","              ","name3@company.com         "

How do I keep the quotes and sort and save as a csv file?

I have the following powershell source script which works with csv files not having double quotes for the columns:

```
Get-Content $Source -ReadCount 1000 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $Delimiter | 
    Sort-Object -Property $NamesOfColumns -Unique |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Each of the values in $ColumnValueFormat must be executed to get the property from the loop variable ($_). 
        $values = foreach ($value in $ColumnValueFormat) {
            Invoke-Expression $value
        }
        # Then the values can be passed in as an argument for the format operator.
        $ShowColsByNumber -f $values
    } | 
    Add-Content $Destination;
```

The `$Source`, `$Delimiter`, `$NamesOfColumns` and `$ColumnValueFormat` are given or built dynamically.

`$ColumnValueFormat` with a non quoted csv file contains:

```
$_.EmployeeID.Trim()
$_.FirstName.Trim()
$_.LastName.Trim()
$_.Location.Trim()
$_.Department.Trim()
$_.TelephoneNo.Trim()
$_.Email.Trim()
```

`$ColumnValueFormat` with a quoted csv file contains:

```
$_."EmployeeID".Trim()
$_."FirstName".Trim()
$_."LastName".Trim()
$_."Location".Trim()
$_."Department".Trim()
$_."TelephoneNo".Trim()
$_."Email".Trim()
```

The problem seems to be based around the `$ColumnValueFormat` that is placing the column headers with the double quotes. (If I remove them I am not sure the internals of the cmdlet will recognize the column headings when it is processing the rows)

I am having two problems:

1. The column heading surrounded by the double quotes. The problem seems to be based around the `$ColumnValueFormat` that is placing the column headers with the double quotes as it does not process the rows. (If I remove the double quotes then it does not recognize the column headings when it is processing the rows).
2. Another problem I came across last minute is if the last column is blank it thinks it's a null and when the `Invoke-Expression $value` executes (where `$value` holds the last column expression of `$_.Email.Trim()` - on a non quoted CSV file) it bombs. If I try to place the statement in a try/catch block it simply ignore it the last column is not added to the `$values` array and again bombs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Simply to process a CSV file whether the CSV file has double quotes for it's columns or not and if the last column contains a blank because it sees a carraige return to allow the Invoke-Expression $value which containts the $_.Email.Trim() expression to execute so it can place an extra element in the $values array which containg a blank (which gets assigned by the completion of the ForEach loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes around property names are used syntactically to access names with spaces, not to write quotes to the output.

`Export-Csv` cmdlet doesn't have an option to force quotes so we'll have to export the CSV manually. And we'll have to process empty values that are `$Null` after `ConvertFrom-Csv` with an empty string. In case only some fields are needed we'll use `Select` cmdlet with `-index` parameter.

```ps
Get-Content $Source |
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    %{ $header = $false } {
        if (!$header) {
            $header = $true
            '"' + (
                ($csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name.trim() |
                    select -index 1,6
                ) -join '","'
            ) + '"'
        }
        '"' + (
            ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value |
                %{ if ($_) { $_.trim() } else { '' } } |
                select -index 1,6
            ) -join '","'
        ) + '"'
    } | Out-File $Destination
```

The above code is great for pass-through processing of large CSV files because it doesn't keep the entire file in memory. Otherwise it's possible to simplify the code a bit:

```ps
$csv = Get-Content $Source | ConvertFrom-Csv
$csv | %{
    '"' + (
        ($csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name.trim() |
            select -index 1,6
        ) -join '","'
    ) + '"'
} {
    '"' + (
        ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value |
            %{ if ($_) { $_.trim() } else { '' } } |
            select -index 1,6
        ) -join '","'
    ) + '"'
) | Out-File $Destination
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Will change my code similarly and let you know. :-)

Comment: One more thing How would you make it dynamic. So you are able to select which columns you want to go to the output file? With my original code I had $ShowColsByNumber as {2},{4}. So I could get my columns I wanted to the output file.

Comment: The usual array selection works: `'"' + (($_.PSObject.Properties.Value.trim() | select -index 1,3) -join '","') + '"'`

Comment: Ok. Great. Will try it and let you know. Thank you for your help. :-)

Comment: Works great! Only hurdle, if last column is blank (with spaces & CR/NL or CR/NL after last comma) it bombs out:

08/23/2016 09:21:44 - - ERROR: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\FileUtilities\FileUtilities.psm1:6421 char:11
+ ...             '"' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value.trim() -join '","') + ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Well, I can't help without a sample of such CSV file. Upload it somewhere like http://p.ip.fi

Comment: Thank you again. I used your p.ip.fi link and pasted a sample which I tested and breaks on the 1st record. How will you obtain the file though? It did not ask to save it under a certain name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121645/discussion-between-costa-zachariou-and-woxxom).

Comment: Because I am sort of new to Stack Overflow chatting and I was requested to move the comments to chat. Not sure if you saw or were notified of me moving the comments to the chat and placing my address link with the sample file in the chat message?

Comment: wOxxOm you are brilliant. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Don't know why I am having such a hard time with this CSV stuff but it looks like I still have 2 issues. 1. After setting up my code to work with your example yesterday. I tried reversing columns and realized the -index does not order the columns the way you would like them to be. It uses the same columns specified in the -index but in the order it was processed. So if the columns are from 0 to 6 and you want columns 1 and 2 but in the order of 2 then 1. It still returns as 1 and 2. 2 If I try setting -index to be dynamic with a variable it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do it manually: `$v=$_.PSObject.Properties.Value | %{ if ($_) { $_.trim() } else { '' } }` next line `'"' + ($v[1], $v[6] -join '","') + '"'`